# Is "Darth Maul: Son of Dathomir" part of the Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon, the-clone-wars

I found [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcD3j1j_TbU) that describes the fate of Darth Maul after his last appearance in the Clone Wars cartoons. It claims to be canon, although no source is cited, and I cannot be sure if the video title is the name of the source.

Can someone verify for me whether this really is what it says it is, and whether it's genuinely part of the Star Wars canon?

Comment: Someone could probably turn this into an answer: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:KB:Fate_of_Darth_Maul

Comment: Yes it's canon. Yes it's dumb.

Comment: @Richard Do you have a specific name for the source?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/DaveFiloni/posts/10152103755565053

Comment: Can you add a description of exactly what you mean by "this fate"?  A question should be answerable solely on the basis of the text it includes, without reference to links or videos.

Comment: But my question is asking whether this video is legit, and where the material shown is from. If I don't link to the video, how do I ask that?

Comment: What happens to Darth Maul in the clip?  That's what "this fate" seems to mean.

Comment: Does the clip show him marrying an Ewok?  Being eaten by a polar bear? Selling his lightsaber to support a drug habit?  Setting himself on fire while deep-frying a turkey?

Comment: I'm not willing to sit through a 15 minute video I'm not interested in just so I can decide whether or not I want to answer the question, and many people would be equally unwilling to sit through it for that purpose.  You need to edit the question so we know what you mean by "this fate" without reference to the video.  "This video shows Darth Maul being dropped into a woodchipper - is this his canonical fate?"  or whatever.

Comment: Note - I voted to close as "Unclear what you're asking", not as a duplicate.

Comment: I thought it was perfectly clear what he was asking. He's asking "is this video canon". Since it's a series of screencaps for '[Son of Dathomir](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Maul%E2%80%94Son_of_Dathomir)', the answer is "***yes, and that's already been covered in an earlier answer***".

Comment: I've made quite a big edit to make it more searchable for future reference. If you feel I've gone too far, press the [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/113533/edit) button and roll it back

Comment: I just read that comic by pausing the video countless times. Well, it's awesome, but in the end Maul escaped.

Answer (score 2):

That video is just posting a series of panels from the comic [Darth Maul: Son of Dathomir](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Maul%E2%80%94Son_of_Dathomir) (for example, compare the middle image from [this review of issue 1](http://www.nexusroute.co.uk/archives/43089) to the one seen at 0:27 in the video) which is indeed part of the new Disney canon. And as Richard pointed out in a comment, [this facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/DaveFiloni/posts/10152103755565053) from Dave Filoni, supervising director of the Clone Wars series, mentions the story was originally going to be used in episodes of that show, but when that show was canceled they turned it into a comic.

Comment: You might want to include [this facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/DaveFiloni/posts/10152103755565053) from Dave Filoni where he talks about how these scripts were converted into comics at the behest of LucasFilm